# $\lim_{x\to 0+}=(1/x)^{\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, trigonometry, exponential-function

$\lim_{x\to 0+}=(1/x)^{\sin x}$

I think I should rewrite it into a from $e^{\ln}$ , but I can't continue the calculation after this step.

Comment: Taking the logarithm is a good idea. What is the logarithm of your expression?

Comment: $(1/x)^{\sin(x)}=e^{-\log(x)\sin(x)}$ what happens as $x$ goes to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin(x)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin(x)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}-\ln(x)\sin(x)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\ln(x)}{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-\ln(x)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-\ln(x)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\csc(x)}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x\cos(x)}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\frac{1}{\cos(0)}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\sin(x)}=e^{-\sin(x)\ln(x)}=e^{-\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot x\ln(x)}.$$

Comment: $sin x /x $ goes to 1 and $ ln(x) $ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: it's not $\ln(x)$ but $x\ln(x)\underset{x\to 0^+}{\longrightarrow }0$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses neither L'Hospital's Rule nor logarithms.  Rather, it relies only on standard inequalities from geometry along with the Squeze Theorem.

To that end, we proceed by recalling that for $x\ge 0$ the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$x\cos x\le \sin x\le x \tag 1$$

From $(1)$ it is easy to show that for $0\le x\le 1$ we have

$$x\sqrt{1-x^2} \le \sin x\le x \tag 2$$

Then, using $(2)$, we have for $0\le x\le 1$

$$\left(\frac1x\right)^{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}\le \left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}\le \left(\frac1x\right)^{x} \tag 3$$

Using $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$ in $(3)$ along with the Squeeze Theorem reveals

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\frac1x\right)^{\sin x}=1$$